# Javascript Error with Inherited Request Object

Tags: javascript, inheritance

for the purpose of tryout I after reading [this mdn article about inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited), I wanted to create an Object which directly inherits from XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
function Request( url ){
    XMLHttpRequest.call( this );
};

Request.prototype = Object.create( 
    new XMLHttpRequest(),{
    'constructor' : {
        'value' : Request,
        'enumerable' : true
    },

    'toString' : {
        'value' : function(){
            return '[Object Request]';
        },
        'enumerable' : true
    }
});
```

That itself does not cause any trouble, but when I try to use a Instance. just after creation the call to the inherited .open( method, location ) -method makes the browser throw this error:

[image: screenshot of error]

Does anybody has an idea why this error is throw? I tried this technique of inheritance with other Objects and it worked very fine, so why not with the XMLHttpRequest?

Greetings philipp

Comment: Checkout the jquery .Ajax() .Post() .Get() Methods they already do something similar to what you want maby ?

Comment: I know that jquery can do everything, so I wanted to try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DOM constructors cannot be inherited from. I wonder you did not get a `WRONG_THIS_ERROR`…

> I tried this technique of inheritance with other Objects and it worked very fine

It works for function constructors because their [`.call` method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4) does similar things as [`[[construct]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) does when called [as a constructor with the `new` keyword](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2).

> Why not with the XMLHttpRequest?

Because it is a native object and its `[[construct]]` will invoke some native code, instead of `[[call]]`ing a function body. Actually it's `[[call]]` behavior will be defined to work as like it was `[[construct]]`, so that `XMLHttpRequest` can be invoked without `new` but will return a new instance as well. You can try `xhr = XMLHttpRequest.call(anything)` - it will not alter `anything`, but return a new object.

Instead of inheriting from it (or even extending the native prototype), build a wrapper around it.